# Unhandled 'error' event on mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I try to find the max id number in mongodb, it doesn't work. What am I missing?

here's my code:

```
router.get('/check', function(req, res, next) {
    var query = news.find({}, {"id":1,"_id":0});
    query.select('id');
    query.exec(function (err, result) {
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain;charset=UTF-8'});
        if(err) {
            res.end(err); 
        };
        res.end(result);
    });
});
```

and here's the error:

```
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (_http_outgoing.js:543:11)
at C:\Users\Romy\WebstormProjects\388-admin\routes\admin.js:44:13
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at the stack trace:

```
TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer
```

Okay, so you're not passing an argument of the right type to a function.

```
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (_http_outgoing.js:543:11)
```

That function is called `end`.

```
at C:\Users\Romy\WebstormProjects\388-admin\routes\admin.js:44:13
```

And you call it from line 44, offset 13, of the file `routes\admin.js`.

It's most likely this line:

```
res.end(err);
```

Because errors aren't strings of buffers. If you want to send back the error *message*, you can use this:

```
res.end(err.message);
```

Also, make sure that once you called `res.end()`, you don't call it a second time, so rewrite your code to this:

```
    if (err) {
      res.end(err.message); 
    } else {
      res.end(result);
    }
```

Or, a bit shorter:

```
    if (err) {
      return res.end(err.message); 
    }
    res.end(result);
```